# Set blur effect in image at touch point area in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, blur

I have made one application.
In this app I can set one image in UIImageView.

Now, when user touch on image, on same pixel I want to set blur effect on touched part.

so pls, tell me how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107979/blur-an-image-of-specific-part-rectangular-circular/14108694#14108694

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the area of blur effect
2. Make an effecct matrix (example matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur)
3. Apply effect matrix to each pixel in the area

And you're done :)